# Status 404 Jersey rest service with tomcat 8

Tags: java, rest, maven, tomcat, jersey

I'm trying to implement Jersey 2.13 with Apache tomcat 8.0.45 and my continuously getting HTTP status 404. I feel like it is because of Jersey version mismatch with the Apache tomcat 8. I tried with different versions, so far no luck. Following is my code and please help me to sort this issue.

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>DMSAPI</groupId>
    <artifactId>DMSAPI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20170516</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>


</build>
```

UpdateUser.java

```
package com.dms.dmsapi.api;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.dms.dmsapi.controller.DbCon;




@Path("/dms")
public class UpdateUser {
    @Path("/update")
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response convertFtoCfromInput(
            @QueryParam("callerNumber") String callerNumber,
            @QueryParam("agentID") String agentID)
            throws Exception {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        DbCon db = new DbCon();
        int resultValue = db.updateBookTaxi(callerNumber, agentID);
        System.out.println("S insert value is " + resultValue);
        if (resultValue == 1) {
            jsonObject.put("result", "success");
        } else {
            jsonObject.put("result", "error");
        }
        String result = jsonObject.toString();

        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
    }
}
```

URL - http://localhost:8080/DMSAPI/UpdateUser/dms/update?callerNumber=123&agentID=123

Comment: Why do you have `/UpdateUser` in your URL? And why do you use a GET to update something i your database? Get is for... getting.

Comment: Isn't that the way we call API, with class name and path? By the way I tried removing UpdateUser. But same exception is returned.

Comment: No, it's not. The class name is completely irrelevant. Show how you configured Jersey. And take some time to read its documentation instead of relying on incorrect assumptions.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check again. But with tomcat 7, this approach is working (with different versions of jersey). That is why I thought this could be because of the version mismatch.

Comment: Can you share your `web.xml`?

Comment: I solved the problem. It was issue of web.xml file and I was calling the API in a wrong way. Thanks @JBNizet . I will share the whole source code as a answer :) .

Comment: Thanks @RishikeshDarandale. It was a issue of web.xml and a way I called the API.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following complete source code and it is working fine.

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>DMSAPI</groupId>
    <artifactId>DMSAPI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

UpdateUser.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.dms.dmsapi.controller.DbCon;


@Path("/")
public class UpdateUser {
    @Path("update")
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response convertFtoCfromInput(
            @QueryParam("callerNumber") String callerNumber,
            @QueryParam("agentID") String agentID)
            throws Exception {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        DbCon db = new DbCon();
        int resultValue = db.updateBookTaxi(callerNumber, agentID);
        System.out.println("S insert value is " + resultValue);
        if (resultValue == 1) {
            jsonObject.put("result", "success");
        } else {
            jsonObject.put("result", "error");
        }
        String result = jsonObject.toString();

        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>DMSAPI</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

URL - http://localhost:8080/DMSAPI/api/update?callerNumber=123&agentID=123

Hope someone will get help from this. Thanks :)

Comment: Dont you have to try like this? 

 http://localhost:8080/DMSAPI/api/update?callerNumber=123&agentID=123

Comment: The `display-name` did the trick I think. But I don't see why an error should result in an HTTP-200. Not a very good example anybody should learn from.

Comment: It was my mistake. I edited the URL. Thanks for the correction @theMind